# How to help portal/community users with out TLS 1.1 enabled?

Tags: security

Salesforce will be phasing out support for TLS 1.0 over the coming year. Browsers will need TLS 1.1 or higher to connect to Salesforce. Users of Internet Explorer v, 8, 9, & 10 on Windows 7 or v. 10 on Windows 8 have TLS 1.1 disabled by default. What is a graceful way to help these users understand that they must enable TLS 1.1 in order to connect to the portal or community? Especially, what is a good way to do this when they first try to connect and are refused?

Comment: Hope that everyone accepts the free upgrade to Windows 10 before Salesforce start phasing out support? If the users are in a company you could use group policy to make the required changes. Otherwise you might not have better options than providing an independent help page with how to configure the browsers. For what it's worth. IE 11 on Win 8.1 has TLS 1.1 and 1.2 support enabled by default.